# Ionic 3 | Set Admob Banner Position inside specified DIV

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, admob, adsense

I'm working on ionic 3 app ( similar to news feeds ) and wanted to show AdMob in it. It is working and it is showing at the bottom of the screen. But I wanted to show it in a Div ( basically I wanted to show it between news feeds ). Is it possible?

If not, is it possible to use Google Adsense inside ionic 3? Where I can place the Adsense tag wherever I wanted inside the HTML.

And is it permissible to use Google Adsense inside ionic 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that you use this [AdMob Free NPM Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/admob-free).
With this module you can specify **banner Ads** only on **top** or **bottom** of your **WebView**. There is no possible way to specify a DIV as position.

However you could go with the AdSense Method.

I recommend this [NG2 Adsense Module](https://github.com/scttcper/ng2-adsense/). It also has a [live Demo](https://scttcper.github.io/ng2-adsense/#/) here.
With this module you can place Ads in your News Feed just like this for example:

```
<ng-adsense
  [adClient]="'ca-pub-7640562161899788'"
  [adSlot]="7259870550"
  [display]="'inline-block'"
  [width]="320"
  [height]="108">
</ng-adsense>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I have seen somewhere that adding 'adsense' as above in the ionic 3 is not permitted ??

Comment: I dont know if thats true. I mean you also can host Ionic 3 Apps in Web. In Web Adsense would be permitted. So I guess it does not have something to do with Ionic itself, I guess its just a rule from Google overall that they want you to use Admob for Apps and Adsense in Web.

Comment: Is it works for you that way I'm trying to use Admobs between content but didn't find a way?